# Is it possible to only show a subset of calendars on the Pixel Watch 2?

Tags: google-pixel-6, google-pixel-watch-2

I have several calendars associated with my Google account. Some are my calendars and others are other people's calendars. I only want to display a subset of calendars on my Pixel Watch 2, but keeping access on my phone and desktop. I don't want certain calendars to show up in the Next Event tile or the Next Event complication.

In the Watch app on my phone, under System > Calendar sync, "Sync calendar" is enabled and only the calendars I want to see are checked. Some calendars are unchecked and I don't expect to see these calendars in the Google Calendar watch app, in the Next Event tile, or displayed on the Next Event complication, but I do.

On the watch, I don't see any settings to control which calendars are visible.

Is what I want possible? If so, how?